# Malachim of Nations constantly fighting?

Tags: gentiles, malach-angel, army-military-war

I think recall learning about how the Malachim of different nations fight each other very often, like raging Bulls, and this causes wars in the Earthly realm between nations. What is the source for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen anywhere referring to them as "raging bulls". However, I have seen the concept that each nation has its own שר, making 70 שרים (see Sukkah 55b). They are the source for the nations themselves and if Hashem makes one of them fall or if a שר of one nation "conquers" the שר of another it has an effect down here. (Similiar to the [concept](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Leviticus.18.25.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that everything in the physical world has a source in the spiritual realm.)

Sources for the above:

See [list of verses](http://tora.us.fm/tnk1/kma/qjrim1/sr_uma.html) that refer to these שרים האומות.

Ramban on Bamidbar 14:19 and [Shnei Luchos Habris](http://file:///C:/Users/mende/Downloads/HebrewBooksOrg_9736_page_244.pdf)

> לכך יאמר כבר "סר צלם מעליהם"...ירמוז **לשרי מעלה שאין אומה נופלת עד שנופל השר שלה תחלה** (מכילתא שירה ב) כענין שכתוב (ישעיהו כד כא) יפקוד ה' על צבא המרום במרום וגו' ואחר כך על מלכי האדמה באדמה וכמפורש בספר דניאל (י כ) יאמר כבר סר הכח אשר בצלו יחיו הגוים וה' המשפיל אותם אתנו על כן אל תיראום וכך אמרו במדרש שיר השירים ונסו הצללים אלו שרי אומות והמלאכים שלהם כי הם הצל על האומות וכבר הזכרתי זה במקומות אחרים (ויקרא יח כה לעיל יא טו)

[image: Sheni Luchos Habris]

These 70 שרים are commonly explained in Chassidus and Tanya as a way that Hashem's "energy" comes down in a manner that is similar to giving something to someone with your face turned away. See Kuntres Umayon chapter 8, [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=15747&st=%25u201Cseventy%20Supernal%20Princes%25u201D&_rnd=0.3777968198211472), and [Tanya epistle 25](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7970/jewish/Epistle-25.htm). Interesting to note that Jews are under the control of the ע' שרים during golus, forcing the שכינה to go through these שרים, which is called גלות השכינה. See [here](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/4313260/jewish/-.htm) based on the maamarim of the Alter Rebbe.